# How to find the number of fields in a structure?

Tags: matlab, field, bounding-box

I am relatively new to Matlab and I cannot find this information anywhere. I am trying to draw a bounding box around a binary image and then resize it.

```
stT = regionprops(binImT, 'BoundingBox');
binImT = imcrop(binImT, [stT(1).BoundingBox(1), ...
                         stT(1).BoundingBox(2), ...
                         stT(1).BoundingBox(3), ...
                         stT(1).BoundingBox(4)] );
resizImT = imresize(binImT,[400 640]);
```

My problem comes when there is more than one bounding box in the image. I want to be able to select the largest bounding box and resize the image inside it but as I cant find how many fields there are in `stT` (I dont know how many bounding boxes will be created in the original image) I cant do this. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are simply looking for:

```
numel(stT(1).BoundingBox)
```

If you are really looking for te number of fieldnames in stT, try:

```
numel(fieldnames(stT))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not the number of fields in the struct, but rather the number of elements in a struct array. You can do:

```
stT = regionprops(binImT, 'BoundingBox'); % compute the bounding boxes for all parts
sz = arrayfun( @(x) prod( x.BoundingBox(3:4) ), stT ); % compute BB area
[maxArea maxIdx] = max(sz); % pick element with maximal size
binImT = imcrop( binImT, st(maxIdx).BoundingBox ); % crop the largest part
```

---

For completeness, to get the number of fields in a struct

```
numOfFields = numel( fieldnames(stT) );
```

To get the number of elements in a struct array

```
numOfElements = numel( stT );
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `regionprops` is an array of structures.  To find the number of elements in this array, just use the `length` function, as for any other array:

```
length(stT)
```